# Xcode 11 / iOS 13 record UITest not working

Tags: ios, xcode

It appears that recording UI Tests on iOS 13 is not working. I press the record button, the app runs and while I interact with it, no code gets generated based on those actions as you would expect. This also happens on a new project.

Is that a bug or is there any new configuration we need to do. I have no ideas on what to do. I think I watched all testing WWDC sessions and don't remember anything being mentioned about this.

If I change the simulator to iOS 12, it works as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be a reported bug already:
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/123069

So we would just need to wait for an update. But yes ios12 still working fine

Comment: has this changed in 2020-12?